# How to view international Google sites to ensure our translated pages are indexed properly?

Tags: google, google-search-console, language, hreflang, translation

We just started launching translations of our site at the end of last year. The first language we launched was Portuguese. I've submitted the new site to Google Search Console but I'm just wondering what's the best way to test how the foreign search engines are indexing the site?

For example, I have my Opera browser set to Portuguese but when I go to www.google.com.br or www.google.pt and search for our brand name the default English site still appears in search results with the message "Traduzir esta pagina" which is "Translate this page" in English.

Do I need to use a VPN service and disguise my IP so it appears as if I'm searching in Brazil or Portugal? I didn't do country targeting in Google search console because I wanted the site to be available to anybody anywhere that speaks the language, but I would still think that Google would provide the appropriate site to the individual especially if the browser language setting matches the default language of the search engine.

I should also mention that I do have hreflang tags in my header both self referencing for each page and the alternates.